# c# MouseUp is ignored while dragging an item to another panel

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, event-handling, treeview

I am trying drag an item from an ItemList to my TreeList.  I wrote `listView1_MouseDown`, `listView1_MouseMove`, `treeView1_MouseMove` and `treeView1_MouseUp` functions. When I move the mouse within treeView1 borders, MouseMove event is handled as it was supposed to. But MouseUp doesn't fire. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is that the MouseMove event fires, it shouldn't.  Clicking and dragging in a list view enables rectangle selection mode.  The mouse is captured.  And the MouseUp event fires in the list view, not the treeview.  Consider using drag+drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, `MouseUp` event is sent to the same control as `MouseDown` was sent to. So, in your case, your `listView1` will receive `MouseUp`.

You might want to look into some other events, like [DragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx).